# SQL Query to display set number of row's data as columns?

Tags: sql

If I have a query that selects the top 5 rows of a table, is there a way to manipulate the SQL to present the values from these five rows as five columns?

Existing Query:

```
SELECT TOP 5 FirstName
FROM USER
```

Existing Result

- Jon
- Bill
- Jill
- Lori
- Rick

Desired Result

- Jon, Bill, Jill, Lori, Rick

*Note: * I've presented the query here in SQL Server syntax, but I would prefer a generally applicable solution.

Comment: *<Removed obsolete comments>*. I also tagged this `[sql-server]` based on the syntax and the OP's previous questions. Please retag if that's not right.

Comment: @NullUserException It's actually a general SQL question, but I put it in SQL Server syntax since most people here seem to know that.  Doesn't matter.

Comment: It matters because there's no standard way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  MAX(CASE WHEN row_id = 1 THEN FirstName) AS Name1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN row_id = 2 THEN FirstName) AS Name2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN row_id = 3 THEN FirstName) AS Name3,
  MAX(CASE WHEN row_id = 4 THEN FirstName) AS Name4,
  MAX(CASE WHEN row_id = 5 THEN FirstName) AS Name5
FROM
(
  SELECT TOP 5 FirstName, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY xxx) as row_id FROM User ORDER BY xxx
)
  AS source
```

Note: Replace `ROW_NUMBER()` (which works in SQL Server) with any function that will allow you to number the records in the inner query; such as `rownum`, etc, depending on your version of SQL.

Answer (score 2):

If you want distinct columns, not just a 1-value list of all the values, try [pivot tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx).

Comment: Good answer and thanks, but I prefer the platform agnostic answer.

Comment: @C.Ross Dems' answer is not platform agnostic. No such answer exists.

Comment: Thanks for the vote of confidence and you are right! To wit, both of them choked like crazy on my 486 under Access 2.0 ;-) What a killer app (double smiley)

Comment: @NullUserException While I understand it's not truly platform agnostic, it can be adapted to other platforms and should work on several databases.  In short, I got his answer to work in my target environment.